# How to filter rows by the result of a calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below code creates a new column "ZScore"

```
SELECT [Cardholder Name], [Debit Amount], ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
FROM ['Card Data']
ORDER BY [ZScore] DESC;
```

What I am trying to do is only display the rows where ZScore is >= 3. I have tried the following but everything seems to throw an error.

```
SELECT [Cardholder Name], [Debit Amount], ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
FROM ['PCard Output']
HAVING (([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ())) > 3
ORDER BY [ZScore] DESC;
```

What would be the correct way to only display rows where the calculated z score is >= 3?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Gordon's subquery answer should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM (SELECT [Cardholder Name], [Debit Amount], ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
      FROM ['Card Data']
     ) cd
WHERE ZScore > 3
ORDER BY [ZScore] DESC;
```